# Lee_background corpus words

Tags: gensim, word2vec, keyerror, word-embedding

Word2Vec models trained on Lee_background corpus is showing following error **KeyError: 'design'**
even though the corpus contains the word three times

1. "The round the world yachts are set for a flying beginning, with a 200-metre headstart **designed** to get them out of harm's way.
2. "It is the latest in a series of attacks **designed** to put pressure on the Palestinian Authority to take tougher action against militants accused of violence against Israelis."
3. "The Cancer Council's chief executive officer, Andrew Penman, says another trend is in the type of lung cancer which is believed to be caused by changes in the **design** of cigarettes."

Can anyone please explain the reason?

```
import gensim.models

sentences = MyCorpus()
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences)

model.wv.key_to_index["will"]
```

O/P: 19

**But,**

`model.wv.key_to_index["design"]`

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7468\4018423340.py in <module>
> ----> 1 model.wv.key_to_index["design"]
>
> KeyError: 'design'
> ```

Comment: I think both edits are saved now, but please check again. You can use the `{}` button in the editor to create source-code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The `Word2Vec()` class has many parameters with default values. One of them is `min_count`. This parameter ignores all words with total frequency lower than the parameter value. The default value is 5, therefore if a word occurs only three times it is ignored.

Note that the word *design* occurs only a single time. The other two occurrences are a different word, i.e., *designed*. Word2Vec or Gensim do not implement stemming or lemmatization by default, if you want these words to be grouped together then you need to preprocess the corpus first.

However, for word embeddings it is uncommon to perform such preprocessing steps. These models represent the occurrence of words in context, and for this context it makes a difference which variant of a word is used. Therefore applications in computing similarity or classification are usually performed on the unmodified source text.

Code to illustrate the parameter setting:

```py
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
from gensim import utils
import gensim.models

class MyCorpus:
    """An iterator that yields sentences (lists of str)."""

    def __iter__(self):
        corpus_path = datapath('lee_background.cor')
        for line in open(corpus_path):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield utils.simple_preprocess(line)


sentences = MyCorpus()
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, min_count=1)
print(model.wv.key_to_index["design"])   # prints 5145
print(model.wv.key_to_index["designed"]) # prints 2795
```

Source: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec (parameter settings), https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html (code for data and model).

Comment: I am highly obliged to you for the quick response with solution. I was stuck in the code since last couple of days.

Comment: Great answer. I would also note that while you *can* use `min_count=1`, this usually makes models worse: `Word2Vec` only makes good vectors for words with many varied usage examples, & spending the effort to try to make vectors for words with insufficient examples tends to even *worsen* the vectors for other (more-frequent) words. So the default policy of completely-ignoring rarer words is almost always a good idea, & your goal should generally be to have training corpora large enough that you're *increasing* `min_count`, not decreasing it.

Comment: (Note: the tiny 'lee corpus' is bundled with Gensim to aid in some unit-testing & very-basic demos that really only show the right *steps* – it's way too small of a training corpus to really show the usual benefits/qualities of the word2vec algorithm. If you're trying to learn word2vec, move to much-larger training data as soon as you can, or you'll be misled about the essentials of the algorithm's behavior.)